# Proving $f_n(z)=\frac{nz}{1+n^3z^2}$ converges uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Show that the sequence of functions $f_n(z)=\frac{nz}{1+n^3z^2}$ converges uniformly on the set $E=[1,\infty]$.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nz}{1+n^3z^2}=0$ so it converges pointwise to 0. So I am going to check if it converges uniformly to $0$.

$|\frac{nz}{1+n^3z^2}-0|\leqslant |\frac{nz}{n^3z^2}|=|\frac{1}{n^2z}|\leqslant\frac{1}{n^2}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

since $|\frac{nz}{1+n^3z^2}-0|$ is majored by  $\frac{1}{n^2}$ that does not depend on $z$. I conclude the function converges uniformly to $0$.

**Questions:**

Is this proof right? If not why? Which are the alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. I would write$$\left\lvert\frac{nz}{1+n^3z^2}-0\right\rvert=\frac{nz}{1+n^3z^2}\leqslant\frac{nz}{n^3z^2} \leq \frac {1} {n^2}$$ instead, to explain the inequaliy. And you should add that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}=0.$